# Does Beedle have a schedule? What is it?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Is it possible to predict where and when Beedle's airship shop will show up? If so, where and when will he appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His shop moves in a clockwise motion around Skyloft's Bazaar during the day.  It resets to its starting position over the Plaza near the Tower of Light whenever you enter Skyloft.

At night, his shop doesn't appear in Skyloft at all... instead, it's docked at Beedle's Island, in the upper-right corner of the sky map.

You can check your map to see where it's currently at in Skyloft; it shows up as an icon of Beedle's face.

Comment: He will also _always_ start at the same position when you go out into **Skyloft** every time.  i.e., starting from **The Plaza** going toward the **Bazaar**.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yeah, I actually meant the Plaza when I said the Tower of Light.  Whoops.  Tower of Light is right next to the Plaza, though.

Answer (score 1):

Beedle make an orbit of the bazaar on Skyloft Island starting very early in the game (you more or less *need* an item from Faeron Woods to ring the bell to get into the shop). Like all shopkeepers and minigames, his face will show up on the map telling you where he is.

At night he is on his island (Beedle's Island) in the northwest corner. If you go to sleep on the bed in his shop and get up at night, you will wake on his island. You need to do this to get one of the Goddess Chests on the island.

Comment: Or if you're impatient, you could skydive into the shelter if you have good control.  You'll probably want to make sure you have enough hearts to survive that fall though as it'll be a bit tough getting your **Sailcloth** out in time.

Comment: While that is a possibility (and a technique needed to get a different chest), its just easier to take a nap to get there. Plus there is the bonus of that island at night.